# Difference between array declaration

Tags: java, variables, object

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};

int[] b = {1,2,3};
```

What difference between a and b? Am I right that first is object and 'a' is a link, and second is a primitive type and 'b' is a variable?  But what advantages/disadvantages have first array?

Comment: I think that the first can be done anywhere, but the second can only be done when initializing a variable. That is:
`int[] b;` `b = {1, 2, 3};` is illegal, but `int b;` `b = new int[]{1, 2, 3};` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an *initialization* like you have there, there is no difference between them at all. They result in the same bytecode. Note that you have to use the first form in an *assignment*, though:

```
int[] b;
b = {1,2,3}; // <== Syntax error
```

> Am I right that first is object and 'a' is a link, and second is a primitive type and 'b' is a variable?

No, in both cases, you have a variable (`a`, `b`) which is a *reference to* the array.