# Is there any difference between ways we are declaring arrays?

Tags: java

- `int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};`

And

- `int[] a = {1, 2, 3};`

Are there any practical differences between those?

Comment: Hope it will be helpful http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Arrays.cfm#.UpHnzdKBnto

Comment: dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558078/declaring-arrays-in-java/19558227#19558227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent, no difference between the two.

`new` keyword creates an *object*.. and you're creating.. an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), which is an object.

See [Chapter 10. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, **arrays are objects** [(§4.3.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)...

Comment: Thank you. I think the question was like: is there something tricky under the hood? Like 'new String("blabla")'

Comment: No. There is no arrays pool in Java. `String`s in Java are special, they are between primitives and objects. Therefore, `String a = "hello";` and `String a = new String("Hello");` are different.

Comment: @ferrerverck You can see the bytecode of the two, it'll be exaxtly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your second form is just syntactic shorthand for the first form. They compile into exactly the same bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

look at the bytecode from compiled class files, There is no difference.

```
public class XFace  {

    public void test1(){
        int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
    }


    public void test2(){
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};

    }

}

Compiled from "XFace.java"
public class XFace extends java.lang.Objec
public XFace();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/
   4:   return

public void test1();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   newarray int
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_0
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   iastore
   7:   dup
   8:   iconst_1
   9:   iconst_2
   10:  iastore
   11:  dup
   12:  iconst_2
   13:  iconst_3
   14:  iastore
   15:  astore_1
   16:  return

public void test2();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   newarray int
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_0
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   iastore
   7:   dup
   8:   iconst_1
   9:   iconst_2
   10:  iastore
   11:  dup
   12:  iconst_2
   13:  iconst_3
   14:  iastore
   15:  astore_1
   16:  return

}
```