# Difference in Array initialization

Tags: java, arrays

While looking over a source file, i saw two ways of array initialization. I wonder is there a difference between

```
int[] value = new int[0];
```

and

```
int[] value_next = new int[]{};
```

?

Comment: No difference, I prefer the first.

Comment: Your second line should say `int[] value_next = {}` to at least show *some* advantage of it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's nice !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there is no difference. It's  [`Syntactic sugar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) in java array declaration.

The first type declaration is less confusing, at least for me :).

**Note:** I'm not sure why you given the length as **zero** while declaring.

If possible, go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/19558179/1927832 for some advantages over another.

Comment: It was just a example. I saw it in "toArray(T[] a)" of a ArrayList where the zero length is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Now the proof (and an exercise):

Create two classes, each containing one declaration. Compile them to get *.class* files.
On each of the two created files, do:

```
javap -c yourClass
```

To see the *bytecode*.

Now you can answer your own question.

Comment: +1 for teaching how to fish. Now save the text of this answer and apply it to every 10th question on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference.

`int[] a = new int[0]` is to be preferred because it shows the intention of creating an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, although in the second case you have redundant `[]`.

Personally I prefer to use `int[] value_next = {}` to create an empty array.

In my opinion, `int[] value = new int[0];` can, on rapid reading, look like you're creating an array with one element in it with initial value of `0`. During a 3am debugging session I really appreciate clarity.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no difference.

Both create an array with 0 elements.