# Array initialized on the spot

Tags: java

Could you help me understand why this code doesn't work because of that array667({6, 6, 2, 6}). But if comment the whole line and uncomment what is commented now, everything works fine.

Frankly speaking, I took this example from http://codingbat.com/prob/p110019. So, this is taken from their exercises. I wouldn't have invented that, but now I'm puzzled why this is not working?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //int[] a = {6, 6, 2, 6};
        //System.out.println(array667(a));
        System.out.println(array667({6, 6, 2, 6}));
    }

    public static int array667(int[] nums) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++){
            if (nums[i] == 6 && (nums[i+1] == 6 || nums[i+1]==7)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: because the commented way is the correct way of passing array of integers. what you are trying {6,6,2,6} is not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating object of array -

```
System.out.println(array667(new int[]{6, 6, 2, 6}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the type of the array  while you are passing inline.

```
array667(new int[] {6, 6, 2, 6})
```

While initializing it, that is in your first case, you have the type on left side.

For clear explanation with an example , Can you please have a look here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19558179/1927832